Plugin.Maui.Audio won't play more than 40 sounds on Android
I'm creating an Android app which should play many different sounds, and using Plugin.Maui.Audio for this purpose. The problem is, when i load a 41st sound, it wont play. No exception is thrown, just silence. Code:
public static class Helper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, AsyncAudioPlayer> players = [];

    public static async Task PlaySound(string s)
    {
        if (!players.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            var snd = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Chitaika.Resources.Sounds." + s + ".wav");
            var p = AudioManager.Current.CreateAsyncPlayer(snd!);
            players.Add(s, p);
        }
        await players[s].PlayAsync(new CancellationToken());
    }
}


I think creating an issue here will give you an answer faster.

I don't know the particular audio player, but isn't creating a player for every sound a little excessive? It could run out of resources after 40.

@PalleDue, these players can play only the file given to constructor

It's correct that the Plugin.Maui.Audio requires a new player instance for each sound.
However, you should not keep references to all instances all the time, that will lead to resource starvation. Instead, you should free the resources of a player instance as soon as you don't need it anymore by disposing it:
// create player instance
var player = AudioManager.Current.CreateAsyncPlayer(stream);

// play/stop
await player.PlayAsync(CancellationToken.None);
player.Stop();

// dispose as soon as it's not needed anymore to free resources
player.Dispose();
player = null;

Holding 40 references to player instances will likely exceed the amount of available resources. You should consider keeping a single player reference instead:
public class SomeAudioPlayer
{
    private static IAudioPlayer _player;
    
    public async Task PlaySoundAsync(Stream soundfile)
    {
        Stop();

        _player = AudioManager.Current.CreateAsyncPlayer(soundfile);
        await _player.PlayAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _player?.Stop();
        _player?.Dispose();
        _player = null;
    }
}

Note that you should probably pass a valid CancellationToken to the PlayAsync() method and keep a reference to it.
